# Replacing a textarea in post meta with wp_editor() Wordpress

Tags: wp-editor

I have textarea for post meta like this:

```
<textarea id ="product_description" style="width: 100%" name="product_description"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_description', true); ?></textarea>


    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'product_description' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_description', sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_description']) );
}
```

i want to change textarea with wp_editor(). Please help me.. I have tried to find various reviews but failed